# Fetching non formatted Product values in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, object, woocommerce, product

I have below formatting for microdata and adding this on **`content-single-product.php`** WooCommerce template. Below is the code I am trying to add:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Product Name">
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="sku" content="Product SKU">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="Product Price" />
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="Price Currency ex. INR" />
        <meta itemprop="category" content="Category Name">
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="http://schema.org/InStock" />
</div>

<div  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
        <meta itemprop="minPrice" content="Special Price">
        <meta itemprop="validFrom" content="Sale Start Date">
        <meta itemprop="validThrough" content="Sale End Date">
</div>

<div  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing">
        <meta itemprop="image" content="Product Image URL">
        <meta itemprop="description" content="Product Description">
</div>
</div>
```

In this **`content-single-product.php`** template, I am adding some code below this line:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_schema(); ?>" id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

I am using WooCommerce functions to fetch product details, but it returns HTML formatted values and I need **non-formatted product values**.

> Here are the TAGs details:

**1. Tags for Product Basic Details**

- **Product Name:**
  `<meta itemprop="name" content="Product Name">` 
  Assign product name under CONTENT . This specifies the product title and will be shown to users during search.
- **Product SKU Code**
  `<meta itemprop="sku" content="Product SKU">` 
  Assign unique product code for your product.
- **Product URL:**
  `<meta itemprop="url" content="Product URL">`  
  This tag contain product page URL from your website. This may be like http://www.YourWebsiteName.com/ProductName.php
- **Product Category**
  `<meta itemprop="category" content="Category Name">` 
  Assign Category Name under which your product is listed on your website.
- **Product Picture**
  `<meta itemprop="image" content="Product Image URL">` 
  This tags contains product image url. You need to put your product image full url here. 
  For example: `http://www.YourWebsite.com/images/product_image.png`
- **Product Description**
  `<meta itemprop="description" content="Product Description">` 
  Include product detail here.

**2. Tags for Price**

- **Price Currency:**
  `<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="INR" />` 
  Mention your product currency here.
- **Product Sale Price:**
  `<meta itemprop="price" content="Product Price" />` 
  This tags will contain product sale price/mrp. This is actual price above which product is not available in market. The price should be a number without separators between thousands or spaces (e.g. '8.99').
- **Product Special Price:**
  `<meta itemprop="minPrice" content="Special Price">` 
  Provide discounted price, offer price or special price for the products. This is not mandatory but important to get top listing in search results. If left blank, system will assign value 0 automatically. The price should be a number without separators between thousands or spaces (e.g. '8.99').
- **Special Price Start Date:**
  `<meta itemprop="validFrom" content="Sale Start Date">` 
  If Discounted price is offered, mention special price start date in DD/MM/YYYY format. If blank, system will assign current date automatically.
- **Special Price End Date:**
  `<meta itemprop="validThrough" content="Sale End Date">` 
  If Discounted price is offered, mention special price end date in **`DD/MM/YYYY`** format. If blank, system will assign date after 30 days automatically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the **current Product object** and for this you will use together [**`get_the_id()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) WordPress function with [**`wc_get_product()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product.html) WooCommerce function this way:

```
$product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID()); // Getting the Product object from current post ID
```

With that **`$product`** object you can access to any raw data for the current product. 
You can use all [**`WC_Product`** class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) properties and magic properties using the arrow syntax:

```
echo $product->property_slug; // displays the product property (if is a string value)
```

*(Here **`property_slug`** should be replaced by one of the properties listed in [**`WC_Product`** class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html)).*

```
$product_id = $product->id;
$product_type = $product->product_type;
$product_post_object =  $product->post; // see below
```

With the **`post`** property you can access to all post object properties (just as in **`wp_post`** table):

```
$product_slug = $product->post->post_name;
$product_title = $product->post->post_title;
$product_description = $product->post->post_content;
$product_short_description = $product->post->post_excerpt;
```

Then using WC_Product class methods, you will get the following:

```
$product_sku = $product->get_sku(); // or $product->sku
$product_url = $product->get_permalink();

// As a product can be in many categories (array)
$product_categories_array = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'product_cat' );
// The categories in a coma separated string
$product_categories_string = $product->get_categories();
```

To get the currency you will use dedicated function get_woocommerce_currency()

For the **prices** you will use related **`WC_product`** **`properties`**:

```
$product_price = $product->price;
$product_reg_price = $product->regular_price;

// Product Sale price
$product_sale_price = $product->sale_price;

// Scheduled  Sale price dates (timestamps)
$product_sale_start_ts = get_post_meta($product->id, '_sale_price_dates_from', true);
$product_sale_end_ts   = get_post_meta($product->id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
```

To format Product Scheduled  Sale price dates in **`DD/MM/YYYY`** format, as they are stored in database as timestamps values, we will use PHP [**`date()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function this way:

```
$product_sale_start_ts = get_post_meta($product->id, '_sale_price_dates_from', true);
$product_sale_start_date = date('d/m/Y', $product_sale_start_ts);
$product_sale_end_ts = get_post_meta($product->id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true);
$product_sale_end_date = date('d/m/Y', $product_sale_end_ts);
```

You can also access to this product meta data using [**`get_post_meta()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) WordPress function, for example to get the SKU you will use:

```
$product_sku = get_post_meta($product->id, '_sku', true);
```

For product image The dedicated function is [**`get_the_post_thumbnail()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) function:

```
$product_image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $product_id, 'shop_single' );
```

But as a product can have or not an image, or even a gallery of images you should look at the code in woocommerce **`templates > single-product > product-image.php`** template…